# Does mysqldump return an error code I can utilize in a batch file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, mysql, errorlevel

Does mysqldump return error codes I can use on a Windows batch file with such code: `if errorlevel 1` and so on?

I would like to verify the success or failure of a backup.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mysqldump returns the following:

```
0 - Success
1 - Warning
2 - Exception
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/error-types.html

So you should probably use `if errorlevel 2` to ignore warnings and only handle errors (depending on your needs and what warnings might occur, of course). Something like this might work:

```
mysqldump.exe --user USERNAME --password=PASSWORD --database DATABASE > dump.sql

REM Check for error
if %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 (goto ERROR)

echo MySQL was dumped successfully     
goto :EOF

:ERROR
   echo Error occured 
   exit
```

Comment: They already said they don't use `bash`, so I took the liberty of editing a little.

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks :) I tried googling but couldn't find anything. Should've gone for the ref documents!